# Subscript out of range when run marco on Macos

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling with the error subscript out of range at the code:

```
Set wsCondition = wbCondition.Worksheets(2)
```

This code is run very well on windows but when I try on MacOS the error occurs. I am a newbie to VBA and I completely do not understand why this error occurs.

Thanks in advance for your guys advice.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub btn1_Click()
Dim i As Double
Dim N As Double
Dim strKeyWord As String
Dim myCount As Integer
Dim OrderCount As Integer
Dim SubTotal As Range, Country As Range, DisCount As Range, Quantity As Range, ItemName As Range, OrderName As Range, RequiredData As Range

Dim wsOrder As Worksheet
Dim wsResult As Worksheet
Dim wsCondition As Worksheet
Dim wbOrder As Workbook
Dim wbCondition As Workbook



Dim OrderFile As String
Dim ConditionFile As String

'Open Order wb
OrderFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set wbOrder = Workbooks.Open(OrderFile)

Set wsOrder = wbOrder.Worksheets(1)

'Open Condition wb
ConditionFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

Set wbCondition = Workbooks.Open(ConditionFile)
Set wsCondition = wbCondition.Worksheets(2)
Set wsResult = wbCondition.Worksheets(1)


With wsResult
    .Range("A1").Value = "Product code"
    .Range("B1").Value = "Order Condition"
    .Range("C1").Value = "Order Name"
    .Range("D1").Value = "Subtotal"
    .Range("E1").Value = "Discount"
    .Range("F1").Value = "Quantity"
    .Range("G1").Value = "Item Name"
    .Range("H1").Value = "Country"

    .Range("A1").Characters(1, 12).Font.Bold = True
    .Range("B1").Characters(1, 16).Font.Bold = True
    .Range("C1").Characters(1, 16).Font.Bold = True
    .Range("D1").Characters(1, 12).Font.Bold = True
    .Range("E1").Characters(1, 12).Font.Bold = True
    .Range("F1").Characters(1, 12).Font.Bold = True
    .Range("G1").Characters(1, 12).Font.Bold = True
    .Range("H1").Characters(1, 12).Font.Bold = True

    .Range("A1").WrapText = True
    .Range("B1").WrapText = True
    .Range("C1").WrapText = True
    .Range("D1").WrapText = True
    .Range("E1").WrapText = True
    .Range("F1").WrapText = True
    .Range("G1").WrapText = True
    .Range("H1").WrapText = True

    .Range("A1").ColumnWidth = 13
    .Range("A1").RowHeight = 17
    .Range("B1").ColumnWidth = 12
    .Range("B1").RowHeight = 17
    .Range("C1").ColumnWidth = 14.5
    .Range("C1").RowHeight = 17
    .Range("G1").ColumnWidth = 99
    .Range("G1").RowHeight = 17
End With

'using the CountA ws function (all non-blanks)
myCount = Application.CountA(wsCondition.Range("A:A"))

For i = 2 To myCount Step 1
    strKeyWord = wsCondition.Range("A" & i)
    wsOrder.Range("R:R").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strKeyWord & "*"

    If wsOrder.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row > 1 Then

        Set SubTotal = wsOrder.Range("I2", wsOrder.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set Country = wsOrder.Range("AG2", wsOrder.Range("AG" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set DisCount = wsOrder.Range("N2", wsOrder.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set Quantity = wsOrder.Range("Q2", wsOrder.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set OrderName = wsOrder.Range("A2", wsOrder.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set ItemName = wsOrder.Range("R2", wsOrder.Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        Set RequiredData = Union(SubTotal, Country, DisCount, Quantity, OrderName, ItemName)
        RequiredData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        OrderCount = wsOrder.Range("A2", wsOrder.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count

        With wsResult
            If OrderCount >= 2 Then
                For N = 1 To OrderCount Step 1
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = strKeyWord
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "Available"
                Next N
            Else
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = strKeyWord
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "Available"
            End If
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
        End With

    Else

        With wsResult
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = strKeyWord
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "No Order"
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "N/A"
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "N/A"
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "N/A"
        End With

    End If
        OrderCount = 0
Next i

wbCondition.Sheets("Result").Activate
wsOrder.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do whether this code is running on a Mac or Win environment. You have to check if a second worksheet exists in the file you open. In your case you could add following code

```
If wbCondition.Worksheets.Count > 1 Then 
   Set wsCondition = wbCondition.Worksheets(2)
else
   ' Do sth in order to fix the error or end the sub
end if
```

If you get a subscript out of range it means you tried to access a worksheet that doesn’t exist. This may happen for the following reasons

- The worksheet name given to Worksheets is spelled incorrectly.
- The name of the worksheet has changed. The worksheet was deleted.
- The index was to large e.g. You used Worksheets(5) but there are only    four worksheets
- The wrong workbook is being used e.g.       Workbooks(“book1.xlsx”).Worksheets(“Sheet1”) instead of       Workbooks(“book3.xlsx”).Worksheets(“Sheet1”)

You find this [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/#Subscript_Out_of_Range)

Comment: Tks for your answer. Help me a lots :D